# Python Update info on Treeview without changing the size

Tags: python, dataframe, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

I have this code where I Read from an Excel File and show it on a Treeview on a tkinter application. When the program starts the Treeview has a size but when I press the Button to open the file again it changes the size and leave a lot of non cover part. This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import plotly.express as px


def opendir():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="C:/Inversiones/",
        title="Open a File", filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"),
                                       ("All Files", "*.*"))
    )
    LoadDashboard(filename)


def buttonopendir():
    filename = path
    LoadDashboard(filename)


def loadTable(Filename, SheetName):
    if Filename:
        try:
            filename = r"{}".format(Filename)
            df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=SheetName)
        except ValueError:
            lblFileStatus.config(text="File Couldn't opened...try again")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            lblFileStatus.config(text="File Couldn't found...try again")
    return df


def ONPanel():
    filename = path
    df = loadTable(filename, 'InfoONs')
    clear_tree(treeDashboard)
    tickerlist['Tickers'] = list(df['Ticker ARS'])

    treeDashboard["columns"] = list(df.columns)
    treeDashboard["show"] = "headings"

    ColWidth = [70, 70, 230, 115, 40,
                50, 45, 70, 80, 80,
                120, 80, 80, 80, 30,
                40, 115, 100, 70, 60]

    i = 0
    for column in treeDashboard["column"]:
        treeDashboard.column(column, width=ColWidth[i], stretch=NO)
        treeDashboard.heading(column, text=column, anchor=W)
        i += 1

    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        treeDashboard.insert("", "end", values=row)
    my_scroll1.config(command=treeDashboard.yview)

    for col in treeDashboard["columns"]:
        treeDashboard.heading(
            col, text=col, command=lambda c=col: sort_treeview(treeDashboard, c, False))
    treeDashboard.config(selectmode="extended")
    treeDashboard.pack()


def clear_tree(tree):
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())


def sort_treeview(tree, col, descending):
    data = [(tree.set(item, col), item) for item in tree.get_children('')]
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for index, (val, item) in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item, '', index)
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda: sort_treeview(tree, col, not descending))


WIDTH = 1800
HEIGHT = 1000
path = 'C:/Inversiones/ONs.xlsx'
tickerlist = {}

root = Tk()
root.title("Obligaciones Negociables")
root.geometry(str(WIDTH)+"x"+str(HEIGHT))


# Recuadro para la Pestaña Dashboard
my_frame1 = ttk.Frame(root, border=5)
my_frame1.pack()


# Recuadro para los Botones
my_subframe = ttk.Frame(my_frame1)
my_subframe.pack()

btnOpenExcel = Button(my_subframe, text="Abrir Excel", command=ONPanel)
btnOpenExcel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30)
lblFileStatus = Label(my_subframe, text='Archivo sin actualizar')
lblFileStatus.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30)

# Recuadro para el Dashboard
my_subframe2 = ttk.Frame(my_frame1, height=500, width=1625)
my_subframe2.pack()


my_scroll1 = Scrollbar(my_subframe2)
my_scroll1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
treeDashboard = ttk.Treeview(
    my_subframe2, yscrollcommand=my_scroll1.set, selectmode="extended", height=37)
ONPanel()

# Configuro el menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=opendir)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the table From what I Read the data:

| Ticker ARS | Ticker USD | Empresa | Vencimiento | Ley | Dolar | Pagos | Min Nom | VN colocado | Amortizacion | Industria | Precio USD | Volumen | Precio ARS | MD | TIR | Prox Cupon | Dias Prox Cupon | Dolar MEP | Retorno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AEC1O | AEC1D | AES Argentina Generacion S.A | 2025-07-14 00:00:00 | ARG | MEP | Sem | 1 | 30513915 | Bullet | Energia | 107 | 3397074 | 88000 | 1,52 | 5,18 | 2024-01-14 00:00:00 | 78 | 822,43 | 116,02 |
| ARC1O | ARC1D | Aeropuertos Argentina | 2031-08-01 00:00:00 | NY | CABLE | TRI | 1000 | 208949631 | No Bullet | Turismo | 99,4 | 105380784,6 | 83248 | 3,61 | 9,5 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00 | 4 | 837,51 | 144,68 |
| CAC2O | CAC2D | Capex Clase 2 2024 | 2024-05-15 00:00:00 | ARG | CABLE | SEM | 1000 | 300000000 | Bullet | Energia | 108 | 0 | 98000 | 0,54 | -1,96 | 2023-11-15 00:00:00 | 18 | 907,41 | 106,88 |
| CP17O | CP17D | COMPAÑIA GENERAL DE COMBUSTIBLES | 2025-03-08 00:00:00 | NY | CABLE | SEM | 1000 | 196110000 | No Bullet | Energia | 63 | 0 | 54745 | 0,93 | 6 | 2024-03-08 00:00:00 | 132 | 868,97 | 66,77 |
| CP25O | CP25D | COMPAÑIA GENERAL DE COMBUSTIBLES S.A. | 2024-02-25 00:00:00 | ARG | MEP | TRI | 1 | 11287128 | Bullet | Energia | 109,5 | 0 | 99900 | 0,42 | -20,57 | 2023-11-25 00:00:00 | 28 | 912,33 | 101,62 |

Comment: Call `treeDashboard.pack_forget()` before `treeDashboad["columns"] = list(df.columns)` inside `ONPanel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of how to fix it is to create the `tk.TreeView` again from scratch:

```py
import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def opendir():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir=".",
        title="Open a File",
        filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"), ("All Files", "*.*")),
    )
    LoadDashboard(filename)


def buttonopendir():
    filename = path
    LoadDashboard(filename)


def loadTable(Filename, SheetName):
    if Filename:
        filename = r"{}".format(Filename)
        df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=SheetName)
    return df


def ONPanel():
    global treeDashboard

    if treeDashboard:
        treeDashboard.pack_forget()

    treeDashboard = ttk.Treeview(
        my_subframe2, yscrollcommand=my_scroll1.set, selectmode="extended", height=37
    )

    filename = path
    df = loadTable(filename, "InfoONs")
    clear_tree(treeDashboard)
    tickerlist["Tickers"] = list(df["Ticker ARS"])

    treeDashboard["columns"] = list(df.columns)
    treeDashboard["show"] = "headings"

    ColWidth = [
        70,
        70,
        230,
        115,
        40,
        50,
        45,
        70,
        80,
        80,
        120,
        80,
        80,
        80,
        30,
        40,
        115,
        100,
        70,
        60,
    ]

    i = 0
    for column in treeDashboard["column"]:
        treeDashboard.column(column, width=ColWidth[i], stretch=NO)
        treeDashboard.heading(column, text=column, anchor=W)
        i += 1

    df_rows = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    for row in df_rows:
        treeDashboard.insert("", "end", values=row)
    my_scroll1.config(command=treeDashboard.yview)

    for col in treeDashboard["columns"]:
        treeDashboard.heading(
            col, text=col, command=lambda c=col: sort_treeview(treeDashboard, c, False)
        )
    treeDashboard.config(selectmode="extended")
    treeDashboard.pack()


def clear_tree(tree):
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())


def sort_treeview(tree, col, descending):
    data = [(tree.set(item, col), item) for item in tree.get_children("")]
    data.sort(reverse=descending)
    for index, (val, item) in enumerate(data):
        tree.move(item, "", index)
    tree.heading(col, command=lambda: sort_treeview(tree, col, not descending))


WIDTH = 1800
HEIGHT = 1000
path = "data.xlsx"
tickerlist = {}

root = Tk()
root.title("Obligaciones Negociables")
root.geometry(str(WIDTH) + "x" + str(HEIGHT))


# Recuadro para la Pestaña Dashboard
my_frame1 = ttk.Frame(root, border=5)
my_frame1.pack()


# Recuadro para los Botones
my_subframe = ttk.Frame(my_frame1)
my_subframe.pack()


btnOpenExcel = Button(my_subframe, text="Abrir Excel", command=ONPanel)
btnOpenExcel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=30)
lblFileStatus = Label(my_subframe, text="Archivo sin actualizar")
lblFileStatus.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=30)

# Recuadro para el Dashboard
my_subframe2 = ttk.Frame(my_frame1, height=500, width=1625)
my_subframe2.pack()


my_scroll1 = Scrollbar(my_subframe2)
my_scroll1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
treeDashboard = None
ONPanel()


# Configuro el menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)
file_menu = Menu(my_menu, tearoff=False)
my_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=opendir)

root.mainloop()
```

Creates this app (clicking on the open file will preserve the proportions):

[image]